# How to build a tree using LazyColumn in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

In my jetpack-compose app, I'm building a comment tree, where the top level, and the leaves, are lists, that would be best to use `LazyColumn`.

This is of the form:

```
List<CommentNode>
...
CommentNode: {
  content: String
  children: List<CommentNode>
}
```

```
@Composable
fun Nodes(nodes: List<CommentNode>) {
  LazyColumn {
    items(nodes) { node -> 
      Node(node)
    }
  }
}

@Composable
fun Node(node: CommentNode) {
  LazyColumn {
    item {
      Text(node.content)
    }
    item {
      Nodes(node.children)
    }
  }
}
```

On the top level, `LazyColumn` works, but it seems I have to use `Column` for the leaves, otherwise I get an unexplained crash:

```
03-29 14:36:38.792  1658  6241 W ActivityTaskManager:   Force finishing activity com.jerboa/.MainActivity 
03-29 14:36:38.902  1658  3033 I WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{d3b902b u0 com.jerboa/com.jerboa.MainActivity}                      
03-29 14:36:38.902  1658  3033 W InputManager-JNI: Input channel object 'd3b902b com.jerboa/com.jerboa.MainActivity (client)' was disposed without first being removed with the input manager!
```

Has anyone had any luck building a variable length tree in jetpack compose?

Comment: Added a composable example

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't think you really need to place one `LazyColumn` into an other one - each of them gonna have it's own scroll logic.

Instead you can place `item` for each node recursively. To do this, declare your function on `LazyListScope`. These are no longer views, since the views will be inside `item`. And I think the lowercase naming would be correct here.

```
@Composable
fun View(nodes: List<CommentNode>) {
    val expandedItems = remember { mutableStateListOf<CommentNode>() }
    LazyColumn {
        nodes(
            nodes,
            isExpanded = {
                expandedItems.contains(it)
            },
            toggleExpanded = {
                if (expandedItems.contains(it)) {
                    expandedItems.remove(it)
                } else {
                    expandedItems.add(it)
                }
            },
        )
    }
}

fun LazyListScope.nodes(
    nodes: List<CommentNode>,
    isExpanded: (CommentNode) -> Boolean,
    toggleExpanded: (CommentNode) -> Unit,
) {
    nodes.forEach { node ->
        node(
            node,
            isExpanded = isExpanded,
            toggleExpanded = toggleExpanded,
        )
    }
}

fun LazyListScope.node(
    node: CommentNode,
    isExpanded: (CommentNode) -> Boolean,
    toggleExpanded: (CommentNode) -> Unit,
) {
    item {
        Text(
            node.content,
            Modifier.clickable {
                toggleExpanded(node)
            }
        )
    }
    if (isExpanded(node)) {
        nodes(
            node.children,
            isExpanded = isExpanded,
            toggleExpanded = toggleExpanded,
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very close, but I can't use it, because I need to be able to hide leaves of the tree, and this requires a remember, and a if (expanded) { nodes(nodes.children) } that is only usable on Composable function.

Comment: @thouliha `remember` should not be used inside `item`, as it will be cleared after the item is scrolled off the screen. It should be stored outside the `LazyColumn`, see the updated answer how you can do that.

Comment: I'm now using this in my codebase, it worked great. Thanks so much!

Comment: Thanks a lot @PhilDukhov, I used this as my tree imlementation starting point!

Comment: This looks like a good start to getting a working tree component - something I wonder about it though is - do I lose any of the benefits of using LazyColumn by using item() instead of items()? If I have a mega-tree with a million children inside some node, how is this expected to perform? Should I instead be using items() over the children?

Comment: @Hakanai First of all, I would try it and see how it works. But yes, according to [source code](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/61b097d1ff953b4a7a3459a67df8dabc2142641d/compose/foundation/foundation/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/LazyListScopeImpl.kt#L40), it looks like you may face some issues, as adding single `item` and multiple `items` has same complexity, which means that when you add them by one you're getting extra N complexity. I don't know how you can improve it - maybe if your data has a certain structure, you can take that into account in the algo.

Comment: @PhilDukhov I hit the issue with nested lazy columns immediately and it wrecked my plans, LOL. It might be possible to get around that, but I gave up on that approach immediately. What I'm doing now is building a list of the currently expanded part of the tree, and putting that inside a single LazyColumn. When expanding the tree, I have to add 1,000,000 elements to the list, but that runs fast enough as to be unnoticeable. I haven't managed to get collapsing the tree to work correctly yet but it seems like this is a viable way to go about writing a large tree.

Comment: It turns out adding 1,000,000 elements is fast but removing 1,000,000 elements is extremely slow [because Compose is calling removeAt individually for each index](https://gist.github.com/hakanai/d5996c147ab84d937f938c3a1a724305). So it's just something about their list implementation in general, which if I replaced it with a performant implementation, might be totally fine to use for this.