# Jetpack Compose: Nested LazyColumn with Animation

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-animation, lazycolumn

I have a layout that represents a tree of answers which may have other sub-answers. I was inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71667299/9723204) and use a nested `LazyColumn` like this:

```
@Composable
fun Questionnaire(answers: List<Answer>) {
    LazyColumn {
        nodes(answers)
    }
}

fun LazyListScope.nodes(answers: List<Answer>) {
    nodes.forEach { answer ->
        node(answer)
    }
}

fun LazyListScope.node(answer: Answer) {
    item {
        Text(answer.content)
    }

    if(answer.selected) {
        nodes(answer.subAnswers)
    }
}
```

As you can see, sub-answers are visible only if the parent answer is selected.

However, is it possible to animate the visibility of such a group of sub-answers?

```
fun LazyListScope.node(answer: Answer) {
    item {
        Text(answer.content)
    }

    // Needs context of a @Composable function, will not compile
    AnimatedVisibility(visible = answer.selected) {
        nodes(answer.subAnswers)
    }
}
```